# Recursive code to traverse through directories in python and filter files

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, subdirectory, os.path

I would like to recursively search through "project" directories for "Feedback Report" folder and if that folder has no more sub directories I would like to process the files in a particular manner.

After we have reached the target directory, I want to find the latest feedback report.xlsx in that directory(which will contain many previous versions of it)

the data is really huge and inconsistent in its directory structure. I believe the following algorithm should bring me close to my desired behavior but still not sure. I have tried multiple scrappy code scripts to convert into json path hierarchy and then parse from it but the inconsistency makes the code really huge and not readable

The path of the file is important.

My algorithm that I would like to implement is:

```
dictionary_of_files_paths = {}
def recursive_traverse(path):

    //not sure if this is a right base case
    if(path.isdir):    
        if re.match(dir_name, *eedback*port*) and dir has no sub directory:
          process(path,files)
          return

    for contents in os.listdir(path):
        recursive_traverse(os.path.join(path, contents)) 

    return

def process(path,files):

    files.filter(filter files only with xlsx)
    files.filter(filter files only that have *eedback*port* in it)
    files.filter(os.path.getmtime > 2016)
    files.sort(key=lambda x:os.path.getmtime(x))
    reversed(files)
    dictionary_of_files_paths[path] = files[0]

recursive_traverse("T:\\Something\\Something\\Projects")
```

I need guidance before I actually implement and need to validate if this is correct.

There is another snippet that I got for path hierarchy from stackoverflow which is

```
try:
    for contents in os.listdir(path):
        recursive_traverse(os.path.join(path, contents)) 
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno != errno.ENOTDIR:
        raise
    //file
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pathlib` and `glob`.

Test directory structure:

```
.
├── Untitled.ipynb
├── bar
│   └── foo
│       └── file2.txt
└── foo
    ├── bar
    │   └── file3.txt
    ├── foo
    │   └── file1.txt
    └── test4.txt
```

Code:

```
from pathlib import Path
here = Path('.')
for subpath in here.glob('**/foo/'):
    if any(child.is_dir() for child in subpath.iterdir()):
        continue # Skip the current path if it has child directories
    for file in subpath.iterdir():
        print(file.name)
        # process your files here according to whatever logic you need
```

Output:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
```